# Word for the text ready to be copied?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If you click on the *share* button at the bottom left of this question, you will see the text already selected, ready to be copied. What do you call this text? My answer is *copied-ready text*, but I would like to have a better name.

Comment: The selection?  The selected text?  The selected URL? Can you give us an example of how you will use the term you need?

Comment: The subsection of all text on the screen which is currently identified as *ready to be **copied*** (or *ready to be **deleted/replaced/etc.*** is normally referred to as the ***selected text***. In some circumstances (such as the "share" button above), the fact that you the user didn't personally select that text using keyboard and/or mouse might justify calling it ***pre-selected text*** (with or without hyphenation, according to your preference).

Comment: *copied to clipboard* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it *automatically selected* text, or *pre[-]selected* text. The second usage, if you need one word, seems to be used quite often ([1](https://community.filemaker.com/thread/137279), [2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14031)):

> Pre-selected text in new FM-14 calculation dialog
>
> Pre-selected text could be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that *pre-select* is a good choice (already mentioned in comments and Vilmar's answer). Another possibility is **auto-select**:

> Here is a function that when called on a particular HTML element will **auto-select** all of its **inner text**.

([www.matts411.com](http://www.matts411.com/post/auto_selecting_text/))

> Auto Select Textarea Text

([css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/auto-select-textarea-text/))

*Copied-ready* does not sound idiomatic to me.